# How can you use a neural network to extract the needed information from social media ads?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, pattern-recognition, artificial-intelligence

How to solve the following problem using neural networks / and machine learning / artificial intelligence?

Input data - is an ad from a channel or group of a social network. For example, this:

> A room for rent in a tqo-room apartment (preferably a married couple),
> the Verkhniye Likhobory metro station in a 3-minute walk. You can move
> in from September 21 The room is large, with a balvony, the apartment
> has everything. A family lives in another room. Details by p.
> 8922five682461.

And I expect the following output result (as human can parse it instead of the artificial network):

```
{
    address: "m. Verkhniye Likhobory",
    releaseDate: "2020-09-21",
    phone: "89225682461,
    isBalcony: true,
    roomsCountTotal: 2,
    roomsCountForRent: 1
}
```

**This is my whole question.**

And **below** are **important notes to it** - *why exactly a neural network is needed here, and it is difficult to get by with algorithms and other simple means*.

- There is no clear address in this ad, but the address itself is present - the Verkhniye Likhobory metro station.
- There were also mistakes in the ad:

  1. "tqo-room apartment" instead "two-room apartment",
  2. "with a balvony" instead of "with a balcony".
- Also, the ad used to bypass the prohibition of some groups to publish phone numbers: 8922five682461.
  And I think this ad is useful in terms of content, because it can lead to conversion, that is, monetization can be done with such data.
  This ad may be in demand, although a lot of data is lacking.

It is necessary that the system be able to extract data from the text and distribute it among the fields of the structure - even when some of the data does not correspond to the standard.

Comment: Honestly, at least half of those can be solved with using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, you don't need machine learning to solve such problem, at least not as a solution to start with. This kind of problems can be easily solved with things like:

- Clever set of regular expressions.
- Using automated spellchecker to fix the typos.
- Using approximate search software, e.g. [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/), that matches words based on their similarities, rather than using exact matches.

Try any of those, or their combinations first. This should solve vast majority of the simple cases. Maybe it would be enough? It it is not enough, you would at least have a benchmark to compare with (if your machine learning solution works not better than this, you'd at least know it is not worth it). Moreover, it can help with solving many different problems:

- It can help with labeling the data.
- You can use it for validating the results obtained using machine learning solution (what are the discrepancies between rule-based solution vs machine learning? what does this tell you?).
- The rule-based system can be used to solve the easy cases cheaply, so you would need to use the machine learning heavy guns only for the non-trivial cases.
- It saves you, and your bosses', frustration, since you would have something that works early on, rather than waiting for the very first results for months till you polish your deep learning model.

Finally, after all this, if you decide to try machine learning, you would be probably interested in *character-level* models. Again, probably best to start simple, with something like character-level recurrent neural network and if this doesn't work well enough, try more complicated models.